# Connecting to a socket.io namespace using the socket.io-client.java library

Tags: java, android, socket.io

I can connect to socket.io web service no problem using this library https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java . I cannot quite figure out how to connect to a specific namespace though. I have looked through the test code and think I might need to create a Manager class.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add code which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Whenever you face the invalid namespace issue while connecting android app with socket.io , it means you are passing wrong socket url.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Manager manager = new Manager(new URI("http://socket.com"));
Socket socket = manager.socket("/my-namespace");
socket.connect();
```

Comment: This helped mi with Invalid namespace error on Android. I had to set "/" as a namespace

Comment: how to add more than name space on one connection and how to chose between them when trying to listen or emit @patrick_corrigan

Comment: @Armstring I'm sorry I don't know. I haven't used this library in years.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is not working for me.

Actually this code works, please use latest version of socket.io client version :
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Add this in your build.graddle :

```
compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

Then you can connect to your namespace with this snippet :

```
Socket socket;
try {
        socket = IO.socket(socket_host + "/your_namespace");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR :", e.toString());
    }
socket.connect();
```

Check this github issue where there are more explanation :
https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat/issues/8